# Get real type of generic method from StackFrame

Tags: c#, reflection

In my logging module I have the line:

`MethodBase methodBase = new StackFrame(2, false).GetMethod();`

The method I inspect is a generic method and defined as `T[] MyMethod<T>()`. Is there a way to get its real type instead of `T` from `methodBase`?

Comment: can you use `GetGenericArguments`?

Comment: Consider adding small sample showing what happens and what you tried to make question better.

Comment: There is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707298/get-generic-argument-type-and-value-supplied-to-a-generic-method with some more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this. The information in the `StackFrame` is retrieved not from run-time information, but from the .pdb information, correlating the return address found in the stack frame with the assembly offsets described in the .pdb. I.e. only the compile-time information is available, which of course is the open generic method.

Note that even if you manually construct a closed generic method and invoke it directly, you *still* get the open generic method from the .pdb. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo miOpen = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic),
            miClosed = miOpen.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

        Type type;

        object[] invokeArgs = { 17, null };
        int[] rgi = (int[])miClosed.Invoke(null, invokeArgs);

        type = (Type)invokeArgs[1];
    }

    static T[] Method<T>(T t, out Type type)
    {
        type = GetMethodType();

        return new[] { t };
    }

    private static Type GetMethodType()
    {
        StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1, false);
        MethodBase mi = frame.GetMethod();

        return mi.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

In the above example, the `type` variable value assigned at the end still references the `{T}` type for the open generic method, not `Int32` as you would hope in your case. This, in spite of the fact that the `Int32` type *is* retrievable from the `miClosed` variable reference.

If you want the specific type information, you will have to provide a mechanism in your code to determine it explicitly (e.g. pass the value of `typeof(T)` to the logging component from the generic method itself). The `StackFrame` class doesn't have the necessary information to do that for you.

Answer (score -1):

Use `GetGenericArguments` off of the `MethodBase` to get what was passed into `T`.

Comment: Sir, I tried `GetGenericArguments` before I posted here, but there is no real type name there, only `T[]`.